# S3 not returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

I am having trouble forcing S3 to set CORS headers on all of the objects it returns from a bucket, though CORS is enabled, as client-side S3 uploads is working, the returned objects do not have CORS headers!

The policy I have enabled is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

An example object URL https://s3.amazonaws.com/captionable/meme/test

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, make sure an `Origin` header with every request. If no `Origin` header is sent, S3 won't send `access-control` headers, as S3 deems them irrelevant (and typically, they are). A browser (for which the CORS mechanism is meant) will automatically send an `Origin` header when doing cross-origin HTTP requests through XMLHTTPRequest.

In case of loading images with `img`, you need to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute. See 
[MDN Documentation on crossorigin attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin). This will cause the browser to send an `Origin` request header like it does with XMLHTTPRequest.

Going by the answer of Sam Selikoff, you may need to change

```
 <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
```

to

```
 <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
 <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
```

I haven't tested this.

Going by Paul Draper's comment on this answer: Watch out for caching issues. A browser may use a cached response that did not include the appropriate `Access-Control` response headers. During development, you can clear your cache. In production, you must switch to a new URL for the resource, if it was used in a static manner before.

Comment: And therein lies the rub. I was creating an image tag, which does not send Origin headers. That said, I expected S3 to always return CORS headers, though it only does so when 'Origin' is specified. 
Thanks for the confirmation that CORS is properly configured.

Comment: In that case, it seems that I should be setting the crossOrigin attribute of an image tag. Do you by any chance know the sup

Comment: I don't have any experience with that attribute. Setting it to "anonymous" might just trigger the browser to send the `Origin` header. Maybe post separate question?

Comment: Also, the request needs to be a GET and not a HEAD. To test this with curl : `curl -iH "Origin: test" http://…`

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, but it is most certainly not irrelevant. If the response without CORS is cached, the next request will retrieve a CORS-less response and fail.

Comment: Adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration> ` workes for me. But this only works if I open developer console and goto networks tab and check the 'disable cache'. Doesn't work without opening the developer console.

Comment: You may need to add `HEAD` to the `AllowedMethod`s

Comment: is it possible to force S3 to send headers back in response even though ORIGIN is not present in request ?

Comment: The CORS headers were not being returned by S3 until we followed this advice: "**In case of loading images with img, you need to add crossorigin="anonymous" attribute.**" Once we did that, CORS was working in Chrome. Thanks @MyrneStol

Answer (score 32):

I also ran into this with an `<image>` tag, and after following Myrne Stol's answer I added the `crossorigin=anonymous` tag to my image tag. I verified that the `Origin` header was indeed being sent to S3, but still, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header was not being sent in response.

I came across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24424491/1406664) and it solved it. I changed the `AllowedOrigin` in my S3 config to this:

```
<AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
```

and now S3 responds with the access headers. Yay!

Comment: @cory-dolphin I think this should be the accepted answer here. I too had the same problem with the image tag and adding these two lines fixed it.

Comment: This isn't working for me (~2 years later).  I've changed the configuration and I'm testing both in Postman & with a <video> tag.  S3 doesn't respond with CORS headers in either case.  Am I doing something wrong or has S3 changed?

Comment: You also have to include an Origin header in any request - this threw me using curl (e.g. `curl -X GET -v --header "Origin: https://www.example.com" https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/asset.ext` )

Answer (score 31):

Chrome has this amazing bug which they won't fix:

[image]

If you're lucky enough to have control over the code that is generating the  tag you can add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the tag.
Like `<img src="foo.bar/baz.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" />`
If you can modify either the URL for the  tag or the URL for the XHR request, you could add a query parameter to one of them to bypass the cache.
Like `foo.bar/baz.jpg?x-request=xhr`.

Safari has this issue too btw.

Comment: NGL I've been struggling to find an explanation for *hours*
this should be upvoted more, as it was the real reason I had issues - I would have never thought that having an <img> (or in my case even *background-image* in css) would change the behavior of the JS code used afterward. You're a savior.

Comment: I think the real issue is that the server varies the response based on whether or not the origin header is included, but doesn't include "Vary: Origin" in the response. So caches are perfectly entitled to return the response without the CORS headers as the server has allowed it to be cached. I assume the server we're talking about here is S3 - I'm posting a bug report to ask them to fix their broken behaviour. The fetch spec has a clear description that S3 is violating: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; Make sure that every image or video element that requests a resource which (somewhere) needs CORS uses `crossorigin="anonymous"`

I ran into this issue for a video element that was exporting to a canvas. The CORS was setup in S3 correctly, but it still gave me an error and refused to play the video.

It turned out there was a second video element pointing to the same resource, and that video element didn't have `crossorigin="anonymous"`. Hence, the second video played fine since it wasn't expecting an `access-control` header, but the server response was cached and blocked the first video from playing because the cached server response didn't have an `access-control header`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced an issue where I was not getting the CORS header from s3 issue is the origin sent from the chrome is with www like `https://www.example.com` while on s3 we have allowed only `https://example.com`
So s3 wont send the CORS in case of Origin name mismatch

Just shared in case someone will face similar situation

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding Metadata:
On the properties of the image go to the Metadata section and add the next feature:

Type - System defined
Key - Cache-Control
Value - no-cache
In this case, the origin automatically appears in the header.