# Getting S3 CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin to dynamically echo requesting domain

Tags: amazon-s3, cors

How can I set the S3 CORS `AllowedOrigin` configuration such that it dynamically echos the requesting domain in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

In the post, ["CORS with CloudFront, S3, and Multiple Domains"](http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/08/cors-with-cloudfront-s3-and-multiple-domains/), it is suggested that setting `AllowedOrigin` to `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` does this. However, S3 returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` instead.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` does not work in my case as I am using `image.crossOrigin = "use-credentials"` in a JavaScript app. With this option, S3 returns `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. Cross origin access to the image then fails because [using wildcard as the allowed origin in conjunction with credentials is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i).

Background for why this is needed:

In my setup, access to images on S3 has to go through our domain, where authentication is required to restrict access and check if an account is authorized to access the images. If it is, the server returns a 302 redirect to an S3 URL.

For the authentication to work, `image.crossOrigin = "use-credentials"` has to be set so that the request hits my server with the required credentials. (Incidentally, when I tested on Firefox 30.0 and Chrome 35.0.1916.153, if `crossOrigin` is set to `anonymous`, credentials are still sent. But not on Safari 7.0.4. Consistent cross-browser behavior could only be obtained using `use-credentials`.).

Because browsers transparently redirects to the S3 URL, credentials are also sent.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

AWS's CORS documentation does not document this, but I managed to get the answer in a [thread on AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=519678#519678), where I found that AWS changed the original behavior of echoing the requesting domain if `*` is being used for `AllowedOrigin`.

To get S3 to dynamically echo the requesting domain, `AllowedOrigin` has to be set as such:

```
<AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer-- it finally solved the issue! I was at my wit's end with this one.

Comment: I'm wondering if this still works, 5 years later.  In a similar situation and can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 9):

For me it seemed to be some kind of caching issue (even though I was not using cloudfront, only S3). Appending a random parameter to the URL fixed the issue for me, e.g.

`https://s3-amazon.com/bucket/file.jpg?d=3243253456346`

I also had the following CORS settings in S3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: This solved my S3 (non-Cloudfront) CORS issue as well. If only the docs provided some sort of explanation for this caching behavior...

Comment: +1 still very relevant in 2022 using S3 link (non-cloudfront) CORS. Even if it pulls from cache, the response still includes the OP's missing headers. Would like to get some technical explanation.