# html2canvas CORS problem when loading image

Tags: cors, html2canvas

I'm using `html2pdf.js` to be able generate PDF documents of WEB pages.

The function is looking like:

```js
html2pdf(someNode, {
  margin: 3,
  filename: 'name.pdf,
  image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas: {
    scale: 2,
    useCORS: true,
    width: 1300,
    allowTaint: false,
    logging: false,
    proxy: 'https://bucket-name.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com' 
  },
  jsPDF: {
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    unit: 'mm'
  },
  enableLinks: false
}).then(() => {...})
```

When I run `html2pdf` I'm getting error:

> Access to image at 'https://bucket-name.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/image.jpg' from origin 'https://client.exampledomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My development S3-like server is always returning `access-control-allow-origin: *` header and I able generate PDF without problem.

However S3 is responding `access-control-allow-origin: https://client.exampledomain.com` only if I set `origin: https://client.exampledomain.com` request header. But in some reason `html2pdf` doesn't add `Origin` header. I tried to change `useCORS`, `allowTaint`, `proxy` parameters without luck.

Looks like chrome is caching requests and [if first request was sent without `crossorigin` headers, then other requests will be send with same headers as first request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570100/s3-not-returning-access-control-allow-origin-headers/30697589). And it is possible to set `crossorigin="anonymous"` for target image. However my image is a CSS image:

```html
<div
  style="background-image:https://bucket-name.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/image.jpg"
></div>
```

And I couldn't find how to set `crossorigin="anonymous"` for background images.

Is it possible to set `origin` header for exact request manually or clear cache using javascript or maybe here is any other workaround how to load cross-origin image using `html2canvas`?

<sub>PS yes I know here is many questions about html2canvas and CORS errors but I already check most of it and did all recommendations mentioned there without any luck</sub>

Comment: If you are using an API, you need to allow cors on the API side. For example, if you are booting the ten hundred with localhost:3000, you must allow 3000 ports on the api side. Also, if you are using google chrome as a browser, there is a plugin called "Cors", you can activate it and try your web page.

Comment: 1. I'm not using API, I'm using direct Amazon S3 URLs to download images. 2. That is not a solution to ask our every customer to install plugin called `Cors`. The problem appear at the production environment

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I gave up and added hidden extra image to be able add `crossorigin="anonymous"` parameter:

```html
<div class="image-to-download"
  style="background-image:https://blahblah.amazonaws.com/image.jpg?placeholder="
><img alt="" style="display:none;" src="https://blahblah.amazonaws.com/image.jpg?withheaders=yes" crossorigin="anonymous">
</div>
```

And replacing `placeholder=` query parameter with `withheaders=yes` to be able use cached resource with CORS headers instead of CORSless one:

```js
html2pdf(someNode, {
  ...
  html2canvas: {
    ...
    proxy: 'https://blahblah.amazonaws.com',
    onclone: (doc) => {
      let img;
      // update URLs to load cached cross-originated images
      for (img of doc.getElementsByClassName('image-to-download')) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = img.style.backgroundImage.replace('?placeholder=', '?withheaders=yes');
      }
    }
  },
  jsPDF: {
    ...
  },
  enableLinks: false
}).then(() => {...})
```