# Workbox unable to cache a specific css file from a react module because of Missing Allow Origin Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vite

I use Vite PWA to configure the service worker for a react site that uses code splitting and lazy loading. The Workbox manages to precache almost all asset files hosted on a Cloudflare subdomain (resources.fakesite.com) mapped to a S3 bucket. But Workbox is unable to cache a very specific css file from `Yet Another React Lightbox` due to this CORS error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://resource.fakesite.com/0.9/assets/index-b9a60426.css' from
> origin 'https://www.fakesite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[image]

[image]

My node server already sets these CORS headers :

```
  const corsMiddleWare = cors({
    origin: ["fakesite.com", "resources.fakesite.com"],
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus:200,
  });

  app.use(corsMiddleWare);
```

I don't understand why other js and css files are able to get cached by Workbox but not this very specific CSS file due to `Missing Allow Origin Header`.

My S3 bucket CORS:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "Content-*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://www.faksesite.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    },
]
```

---

Updated:

This could be related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55265139/2598292.

I used the console tool to send two fetch requests:

[image]

```
1.fetch(https://resource.fakesite.com/0.9/assets/index-b9a60426.css`)
2.fetch(https://resource.fakesite.com/0.9/assets/index-b9a60426.css?x-request=xhr`)
```

The second one works without the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error.

Comment: Either `https://resource.fakesite.com/0.9/assets/index-b9a60426.css` isn't served by your node.js server, the CORS configuration isn't applied to that particular URL, or there's a cache between you and the server which has an old version of the data without the header. It's hard to tell which, but the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: This could be the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55265139/2598292

Answer (score 0):

The missing CORS origin for that specific file is `www.fakesite.com`, and not `fakesite.com`, so you may just need to add it to your policy array:

`origin: ["fakesite.com", "www.fakesite.com", "resources.fakesite.com"]`.

This would probably work too: `origin: ["*.fakesite.com"]`