# Background image not loading when within <style> tags. It works fine when styled within the <div> itself. Not an incorrect filepath problem

Tags: html, css, django, background-image, content-security-policy

I am unable to put a background image into the `<style>` tags and I don't know why it's not working.

All of the following was done on my local machine. My website is also hosted on a Linode server.

I have the following code, which works fine. It sets the background image in a style directly in the `div` within the body (via Django):

```
<body>
    <div class="scroll-container" style="background-image: url('{% static 'myapp/scroll-L.jpg' %}');">
    </div>
</body>
```

And when I load the page you can see the scroll image loads fine (image1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeOaq.png)

However when I put the background image into the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` everything starts to go wrong:

```
<style>
    .scroll-container {
        background-image: url("../../static/myapp/scroll-L.jpg")
    }
</style>
```

When I load the page you can see the scroll image doesn't load (image2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTn7R.png)

I can't use Django's `{% static ... %}` within the head style tags so that didn't work.

It's clearly something to do with the object storage (eu-central-1.linodeobjects) but I don't know what. Why would it work when using the image in the `div` style and not within the `style` tags?

I've searched around for about 2 hours trying to find a fix but I can't figure it out.

The file path is correct however just for confirmation I have tried the following with no success:

```
.scroll-container {
    background-image: url("static/myapp/scroll-L.jpg")
}

.scroll-container {
    background-image: url("/static/myapp/scroll-L.jpg")
}

.scroll-container {
    background-image: url("/../../static/myapp/scroll-L.jpg")
}

{% load static %}
.scroll-container {
    background-image: url("{% static 'myapp/scroll-L.jpg' %}")
}
```

And I need to do something other than put the background image directly in the div because I am sorting out the `CSP` for my site, and I can't set a `nonce` or `hash` for it if it is a style set directly to the div.

I also tried putting the image directly in the templates folder so that I could just call:

```
.scroll-container {
    background-image: url("scroll-L.jpg")
}
```

However that didn't work either. I also tried putting it into the `master.css` with little success.

EDIT: Here is the code for my object storage in settings.py:

```
# Object Storage for Django static files (https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/linode-object-storage-for-django-static-files/)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

LINODE_BUCKET = os.environ.get('LINODE_BUCKET', 'hmst-bucket')
LINODE_BUCKET_REGION = os.environ.get('LINODE_BUCKET_REGION', 'eu-central-1')
LINODE_BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('LINODE_BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY', '#')
LINODE_BUCKET_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('LINODE_BUCKET_SECRET_KEY', '#')

AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = f'https://{LINODE_BUCKET_REGION}.linodeobjects.com'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = LINODE_BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = LINODE_BUCKET_SECRET_KEY
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = LINODE_BUCKET_REGION
AWS_S3_USE_SSL = True
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = LINODE_BUCKET

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
```

Comment: Do you get 404 errors in your console? Or if you inspect the element, do you get CSS errors?

Comment: Yes, it's a 404 error: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/myapp/scroll-L.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I see that the image is hosted on Linode objects. Are you using a plugin like `django-storages`?

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the code related to object storage. There have been no issues with images that I have used simply as an `<img>` within the website.

Comment: I think this thread has some solutions for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169438/background-imageurl-not-working-for-amazon-s3-image

Comment: Thanks @lucutzu33, it could well have been a solution however as I investigated changing the CORS on my project it became slightly overwhelming in terms of my level of understanding. The solution I have answered below worked out well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was a fix for anybody that has the same problem in the future.

Instead of calling the file path to the background image, I instead called the image from my Object Storage bucket directly:

```
<style>
    .scroll-container {
        background-image: url("https://hmst-bucket.eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/myapp/scroll-L.jpg");
    }
</style>
```

This then gave a 403 (Forbidden error) with the following message when I tried to open the image:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<BucketName>hmst-bucket</BucketName>
<RequestId>#</RequestId>
<HostId>#</HostId>
</Error>
```

So I then needed to change the permissions of the Access Control Lists (ACLs). I changed the Bucket Level ACLs and the Object Level ACLs of my object storage from `Private` to `Public Read`.

I use Linode, so to do this I followed this guide: https://www.linode.com/docs/products/storage/object-storage/guides/acls/. To change the Object Level ACL the guide says you'll need to click the more options ellipsis and select *Details*, however this is out-dated and you'll need to click the actual object itself.

Changing these permissions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use s3 storage as CloudFront(CDN). So you need to config **AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN** variable.

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'cdn.mydomain.com'
```

Official django-storages documentation. [Click to check](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#cloudfront)