# Download picture from S3: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, download, cors

I'm trying to download from a VueJS front-end an image that is stored into my S3 bucket but I always receive a cors error. I've tried several Cors Configuration for my bucket such as:

```xml
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://******.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/#/</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've tried with to change the origin for * and its not working. I'm always receiving

> OPTIONS
>   https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-*********.s3.amazonaws.com/da2f83b3-3563-2d3a-b421-7ce3832f7132.png
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-*********.s3.amazonaws.com/da2f83b3-3563-2d3a-b421-7ce3832f7132.png'
>   from origin 'http://********.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

Here is my call on front-end:

```js
savePicture() {
  axios({
    url: "https://*****.s3.amazonaws.com/da2f83b3-3563-2d3a-b421-7ce3832f7132.png",
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob',
  })
```

I've double checked my config with the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: What are the exact request and response headers?

Comment: @Phil My bad on that, bad copy past, it got quotes in my code

Comment: It really just looks like your CORS configuration isn't applied to the bucket you're trying to fetch from. See [Troubleshooting CORS Issues - Verify that the CORS configuration is set on the bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header) ?

Comment: @awran5 Yes, I did, doesnt work for me

Comment: @Phil According to your link, if I see the Cors Configuration Tab in the permission menu, the CORS config is set. I see it, so I suppose it is done.

Comment: That's not what it says at all... _"If the CORS configuration is set, the console displays an **Edit CORS Configuration** link in the Permissions section of the Properties bucket"_. Do you see _"Edit CORS Configuration"_?

Comment: Did you also check @awran5's link? Seems quite common for people to miss hitting "Save"

Comment: @Phil Indeed, it's kinda common issue. Beside the accepted answer, there are some solutions may work.

Comment: @Phil There is no "Edit Cors Configuration", only the tab Cors Configuration, in the permissions, which bring me to the Cors Configuration Editor. This is what I what I thought was the Edit CORS configuration. I'll keep going through the answer of awran's link. That being said, I've deployed my front-end as a static page in S3 too and changed my <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin> tag for the URL provided by AWS. Still an Error, but not quite de same. I've updated my original post.

Comment: Have you clicked "Save" after editing your CORS configuration?

Comment: @Phil yes, I've checked a couple of time

Comment: just to confirm, the cors policy is enabled onbucket  "elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1**" ?

Comment: @JamesDean If I select my bucket, there is an informational window that appear and under the Permission section, there is CORS Configuration : Yes. So I would say yes, it is enabled.

Comment: @Gleyak Thanks, I was just confirming because the cors should be enabled on bucket  elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1, not on the one which you're using as static website endpoint.

Comment: I've found a work around. Instead of making an HTTP call in my front-end, I'm using the S3Client from java. Everything is good when I call from the backend.