# Kendo-React-PDF PDF Export not displaying image from S3 bucket: “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”

Tags: reactjs, pdf, amazon-s3, cors, kendo-react-ui

**Edits before bounty:** Here is a screenshot of the error I am receiving in my chrome devtools console:

[image]

Here is the exact CORS configuration that I am currently using for my S3 bucket `cbbteamlogos`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

My S3 bucket policy is blank, and I'm not quite sure what to add here, despite the suggestion in the comments below to add a bucket policy.

[Here is the Kendo React PDF docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/pdfprocessing/) that I have been using to implement this, and [here is a part of the docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/drawing/limitations-browser-support/#toc-images) that talks about limitations with drawing images using Kendo.

Having images from this S3 bucket display in my downloaded React PDFs is very important, as I have been building out this PDF generation component for the last week with the assumption that i would get this resolved.

Please let me know if i can share any other output from my app, info on my S3 bucket, etc. that will help resolve this issue!

**Original Post**:

I am attempting to create a PDF generation tool in my React application, and I am using Kendo React PDF for this. However, I am struggling to have images display in the downloaded PDFs. Apologies in advance that this isn't a reproducible example, but the question is high-ish level and I'm not sure a reproducible example would help anyway.

Here is what the PDF is supposed to look like.

[image]
... and here is what it actually looks like when the PDF is exported...

[image]

The issue is that the Stanford logo is not appearing in the downloaded PDF, and I'm not quite sure why. I have been reading the Kendo docs, and it mentions [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/drawing/limitations-browser-support/#toc-images) that images are only exported if the server provides permissive Cross-Origin HTTP headers.

The team logos is saved to an S3 bucket of mine (updated CORS configuration above in edits), however the CORS configuration doesn't seem to be helping. Does anybody else with experience using Kendo-React-PDF have any suggestions on how to get the image to show in the downloaded PDF? I'm not quite sure what else to do to resolve the errors.

Thanks!

**Edit:** `https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1574/25734996011_637430f5d8_c.jpg` this is the source of the landscape image that **is** properly exporting into the PDF, and `https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/STAN-logo.png` is the link to the Stanford logo that is not exporting to the PDF.

**Edit4:** Error message:

> Access to image at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/STAN-logo.png' from origin 'https://cbbanalytics.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is a *very large* (how do I make this smaller?…) image of some info for the S3 bucket that holds the image. I've also updated the post above with the current CORS configuration, which is not working. **Do I need a bucket policy for this?** Is there any other info on the s3 bucket I can share to help with this?

[image]

Comment: the missing resource is `https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/STAN-logo.png`, so being served from https.

Comment: Just realized that i'm getting this error in the devtools - "Access to image at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/STAN-logo.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

As obvious as it sounds, i didnt think to check the devtools console for errors because this isn't an error that was breaking my app, only omitting the image from the downloaded PDF.

Comment: I receive the same error from the production version of the app, with the website name in place of localhost:

Access to image at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/STAN-logo.png' from origin 'https://cbbanalytics.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I am not getting any `mixed content` error

Comment: Did you try a bucket policy that allows read and list bucket to all?

Comment: I have no bucket policy on the S3 bucket, so no I have not tried this. I will look into it.

Comment: The image is now loading with cors headers, I guess the issue was MaxAgeSeconds 3000, the cors settings updates after the specified seconds.

Comment: The image has always loaded fine **on my own website**, it is the specific instance where I use Kendo-React-PDF's download feature that the image doesn't show.

Comment: I can make a fetch request from your website console to load the image now with proper cors headers, So check it now, I think it has resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order get cross-origin headers back from S3, it seems you need to add the following attribute

```
crossorigin="anonymous"
```

to your image tag.  I found this buried in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35278803/819019) at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header) which is similar to yours.

So, in your standford logo image tag - you need to add the attribute:

```
crossorigin="anonymous"
```

In other words, if before, your img tag was:

```
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/STAN-logo.png" />
```

then change it to:

```
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/STAN-logo.png" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

---

### Proof

I wrote a small index.html and linked in your standford logo without the crossorigin attribute and got the following headers back:

[image]

after adding the crossorigin attribute to the standford logo image tag, I got the following:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response on this. This is incredibly helpful, but I will not have a chance to try to implement for a few more days.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not supported on IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: logoUrl, method: "GET", headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache" } }} />
```