# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/Learn.svg' from origin 'https://php.example.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

We have used WordPress Pro plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/ with Amazon s3 bucket.

We have to get this error on SVG extension.

We used below code in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

Below header type code in the server config file

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: S3 doesn't support `.htaccess` — it isn't running Apache HTTPD.

Comment: The requests are going to S3 so s3 should provide cors headers, check if cors policy is enabled on s3 and you're not getting 403.