# Video.js - HLS => No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header [S3, CloudFront]

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, video.js

I have a problem to play HLS videos using video.js plugin in my application.
I have an S3 storage of HLS videos(.m3u8, .ts) and its connected to cloudfront. Videos are working on safari, but they are not working on chrome properly. They work on chrome just when I hard reload the page(remove cache,cookies,...).

[image]

[image]

### My configurations:

**Video.JS:**

```
videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function (options) {
      options.headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      };
      return options;
    };
```

**S3 bucket CORS:**

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Connection",
            "Content-Length"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

**CloudFront:**

[image: Cloudfront]

[image: Cloudfront]

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should not be sent as a request header. See e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19939041/740233 for setting up CORS on S3.

Comment: @misterben If you mean in Video.js, it was placed there as the last try to fix it, so it was not working even without this in request from the video plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem. In my case, some files were received successfully but others (in the same dir, uploaded at the same time by the same mechanism) threw CORS error.
After days of investigation, I fixed it (I hope). I leave what I figured out here for future researchers.

- The CORS support is implemented in S3 and there is a lot of info on the Internet about how to configure it.
- When the CloudFront link is requested AWS checks if there is a requested object in the CloudFront cache. If yes, CloudFront returns it. If not, CloudFront requests it from the origin (S3 in my case), caches it, and returns.
- When the S3 link is requested and there is an `origin` header in the request S3 returns the file with `access-control-allow-origin` header, otherwise, `access-control-allow-origin` is not added to response headers.
- When CloudFront requests a file from the origin (S3) it can transit request headers (that were sent with file request) to the origin (S3). That's why you have to add the `origin` header (and any others) to 'Choose which headers to include in the cache key.' In this case, if the request to CloudFront contains the `origin` header it will also be sent to S3. Otherwise, CloudFront will request a file from the S3 without the `origin` header, S3 will return a file without the `access-control-allow-origin` header, and a file without headers will be cached and returned to the browser (CORS error).
  [headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTz0Q.png)
- Now there are 2 options under cache and origin settings: 'Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)' and 'Legacy cache settings' (seems like earlier there weren't options and just settings from the 'Legacy cache settings' existed). Under 'Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)' there are 'Cache policy' and 'Origin request policy - optional' sections. If the predefined recommended policies are set, the `origin` header (and others) are predefined for 'Origin request policy - optional' but not for 'Cache policy'. To be honest, I don't understand the exact meaning of each but seems like legacy 'Choose which headers to include in the cache key' is now divided into 2 sections. And you have to create a new Cache policy (duplicate of recommended) and add the headers (the same as in CORS-S3Origin policy) if you use 'Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)' instead of 'Legacy cache settings'.
  [recomended settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08vKY.png)  [cors-s3origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkred.png)  [cachingoptimised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZQeC.png)
- In my case, if the files were requested from a mobile app the first time, the requests didn't have the `origin` header. That's why S3 returned them without the `access-control-allow-origin` header and they were cached in CloudFront without headers. All next requests with the `origin` header (browser always add this header when you make a request from js) failed because of CORS error ("No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'...").
- There is an ability to add custom headers to requests from CloudFront to S3 (Origins -> Edit particular origin -> Add custom header). If you don't care from where users request your files, you can add the `origin` header here and set it to any value. In this case, all requests to S3 will have the `origin` header.
  [custom header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atNMd.png)
- There are a lot of CloudFront edge locations. Each of them has its own cache. The user will receive files from the nearest one. That's why it's possible that some users receive files successfully, but others get CORS errors.
- There is an `x-cache` header in CloudFront response headers. The value can be either "Miss from cloudfront" (there is no request file in the cache) or "Hit from cloudfront" (the file returned from the cache). So, you can see if your request is the first to a particular edge location (disable browser cache in devtools if you want to try). But sometimes it behaves like randomly) and I don't know why.
- Looks like even the same edge location can have different caches for different clients. I don't know what is it based on, but I've tried to experiment with browser, Postman, and curl, and have got the next results (I've tried many times with different files and different ordering - the request from the curl doesn't see the cache created for browser and Postman, and vice versa):

  1. the request from the browser returns "Miss from cloudfront";
  2. the request from the browser returns "Hit from cloudfront";
  3. the request from the Postman returns "Hit from cloudfront";
  4. the request from the curl returns "Miss from cloudfront";
  5. the request from the curl returns "Hit from cloudfront".

As AWS docs are quite poor about this question and support just recommends reading the docs, I'm not sure about part of my conclusions. That's just what I think.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was due to the cache in CloudFront, so you need to invalidate the cache in AWS CloudFront. When you invalidate the cache in CloudFront, it immediately stops serving the cached version of the file and sends a new request to the origin server the next time someone requests the file. Here are the steps to invalidate the cache in CloudFront:

1. Open you AWS Management Console and navigate to the CloudFront section.
2. Select the distribution that serves your content.
3. Find the "Invalidations" tab and click the "Create Invalidation" button.
4. In the invalidation request, you specify the path(s) of the file(s) you
   want to invalidate. You can use the asterisk (*) wildcard to invalidate multiple files. For example:
   To invalidate a specific file, enter its path, like /artist_videos/your_hls_video.m3u8.
   To invalidate all files, you can use /*, which removes all files from CloudFront's cache.
5. Submit the Invalidation Request