# Can I upload form-data files to S3 via AWS API-Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, api-gateway

In AWS environment I want to upload a file to S3 via API gateway. I can't use lambda, because the 6MB payload limit. (The API gateway's 10MB limit is fine.) I could manage to upload a file with POST request and binary body. My question is how can I upload a picture which is wrapped in a multipart/form-data and can I set a file size and format limitation without using lambda functions?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use presigned URLs with S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use aws-sdk to create the API end point and get the url:

- **API Code [(aws-sdk API Doc)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)**:

  - for upload, reference `s3.getSignedUrl('putObject')`
  - **Don't use `S3.putObject` for upload document, it is a difference concept**
  - Example:

    ```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = this.S3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
      Expires: expires_second
    })
    return resolve(url)
    ```
- **S3 Bucket Config [(Reference Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header)**:

  - Select your bucket
  - Permissions Tab > Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) > Edit

    ```
      [
        {
          "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*",
            "Authorization"
          ],
          "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
          ],
          "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
          ],
          "ExposeHeaders": [],
          "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
        }  
      ]
    ```
  - Confirm your `AllowedMethods` existing `PUT` method
- **Upload Document(Postman case)**

  - Copy and paste the link which get from `s3.getSignedUrl('putObject')`
  - Body tab > binary > select you document
  - Headers > uncheck 'Content-Type', 'User-Agent'
  - [Optional] if u want to accept selected file type, edit `{ Accept: '*/*'}`

    - Example: `{Accept: 'image/png' }`
  - Send with **PUT** method
- now you may check the s3 bucket

*other helpful reference*:
https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d

Comment: idea from AWS blogs part [`Overview of serverless uploading to S3` point 2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/)