# Sometimes I get a cors error in images belonging to the same domain

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, cors

I'm facing CORS issues in my Node.js and Express.js application, where some images under the same domain trigger errors, while others work fine. I get this error especially when I send an image download request to the browser. How can I identify and resolve the root cause of this problem despite having CORS settings in my index.js file? How can I troubleshoot this?

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
```

When downloading some images under the same domain, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://XXX.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.net/XXX-image.jpg' from origin 'www.XXX.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**But in some of them I download photos and do not get a cors error, and they happen under the same application**

i made my aws s3 bucket cors settings as follows.

[image]

The root cause of this issue could be various factors. I've been struggling with this problem for days and seeking assistance because I couldn't resolve it. I can provide additional information, especially regarding code snippets and AWS S3 configurations, when needed.

Comment: What do you mean by same domain? if the image is downloaded from s3 directly while your web page hosted at www.xxx.com then that request is already a cross domain request, are you facing similar issue for all images hosted at s3? or only for some? Also have tried clearing the cache as mentioned in this answer for chrome? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54592116/4168998

Comment: from a web application hosted by me, I can download some images, but I can't download some, they're all looking at the same bucket, and the cache has also been cleared. But the problem persists

Comment: Are you manually downloading the images or are these images embedded in frontend app? In any case can check what are the headers being sent for a successful image fetch vs one that's having cors errors in network tab of development tools in browser?

Comment: When making a GET request to retrieve images while downloading a PDF, I'm encountering a CORS error and receiving a 504 error when using axios on the server. Why could this be happening? The same request works fine locally, but the response time is excessively long