How to fix CORS for front-end/client request using axios?
I made a simple video player and want to use different src files. None of the files are on the same server as the application.
The video code is like this:
<video preload="metadata" @play="onPlay" @pause="onPause" :src="https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_960x400.mp4">
</video>

If I run the above code, it works fine without any CORS warning.
However if I perform a get of the file using axios:
await axios.get('https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_960x400.mp4', {
          withCredentials: false,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': 86400
          }
        })

Then it leads to this CORS error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
the remote resource at
https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_960x400.mp4. (Reason: CORS request
did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I am using Node.js with Express on the backend, but my files are not being served via my backend because they are hosted in the cloud.
My questions are:

Why is there no CORS error when the video tag gets the file?
Why does axios cause a CORS error?
How do I fix this?


Because loading something through src isn't the same thing as fetching it. It doesn't make sense to add cors-related headers to a request in the first place. Cors is supposed to prevent remote data from being accessed in disallowed ways, it's not that clients can give themselves a permission to access it. Probably this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header

Those headers are supposed to be sent from the server to the client.  If you add them to the client 1) they won’t work and 2) you are actually increasing the odds that your request doesn’t conform to cors, as it now requires a pre flight check due to unauthorized headers being sent.

Does this answer your question? Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?

@estusflask i just put them in there because i didnt understand what was going on with CORS. on the backend I could use npm cors middleware but from the front-end i am at a loss as to what the issue is. do you mean that AWS S3 is blocking the request or my browser? i dont understand what is the CAUSE of the CORS error.

@volumeone Yes, it's s3 that blocks it by default AND it relies on browser's native behaviour regarding cors to make it so. The solution is the same as with your own webserver, you need to configure s3 to allow certain cors requests, or you have to resort to proxying the requests through your backend to avoid cors if this s3 doesn't belong to you

@EstusFlask so if S3 is not blocking anything, then its the browser's native behaviour that is blocking the cross-origin request? In that case, "proxying" it through my own server API should solve it?

@volumeone Yes, that's how cors basically works. You can directly fetch cors-protected resource on server side but not on client

CORS policy is defined by servers. The video's owning server defines who and how anyone can access its resources. So, if you cannot access the video using axios, but can do so using the video tag, it means that the server that owns the video is configured to allow the video to be loaded in the HTML through the browser, but does not allow it to be loaded by the axios module.
If you have control over all the videos that will appear in your application one by one, might program a way to choose how to show the video using the tag or loading with axios in your posting interface, that way you will be able to test if the video will be displayed correctly before you post it.
But if your app loads these videos automatically, you might program the pages to hide the videos that your app cannot access, or loading the title and link but showing "This video can't be loaded" instead its thumbnail.
